# Cannot cast object jars with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'. when upgrading from grails 3.0.10 to 3.1.11

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm  upgrading my application from grails 3.0.10 to 3.1.11. When I run the `grails clean` command it shows the following error when reading my `.gradle` folder dependencies.

| Error Error initializing classpath: Cannot cast object 'file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore/ana/1.8.2/8f6699fd8c146236789f7672ee0a1df9718b259d/ana-1.8.2.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore/fatFooter/1.8.2/937af4c115732e561234aa6e42876f6aa394082a/fatFooter-1.8.2.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore/widgetManager/2.4/bc8d041cc451cbca85e89596a9b9050880e2aa26/widgetManager-2.4.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore/pdCommon/1.1pojo/cc4b09ba682fcb0ec3cd738dbbb47026bb42eb1c/pdCommon-1.1pojo.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore.grailscore/grailscore/2.8.1/9eecb9f37cf1b0908ae73360144328d45ff3759d/grailscore-2.8.1.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nnacres.nncore/jsCss/1.3pojotemp/c203c8e38668a6c593ff2765a845ed8776866152/jsCss-1.3pojotemp.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/3789d9fada2d3d458c4ba2de349d48780f381ee3/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails.plugins/asset-pipeline/3.2.1/32a127d37d6deeac5916b256db8b0fe8b3a9a9ad/asset-pipeline-3.2.1.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/dbbd7cd309ce167ec8367de4e41c63c2c8593cc5/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.grails/grails-plugin-testing/3.1.11/ced629bc229c0d9b463a958ad2770eb4f4a85443/grails-plugin-testing-3.1.11.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/23457ad1cf75c2c16763330de5565a0e67b4bc0a/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar file:/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.1/87c0ea803b69252868d09308b4618f766f135a96/objenesis-2.1.jar' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'

at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.MapReadingCachedGradleOperation.readFromCached(MapReadingCachedGradleOperation.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.MapReadingCachedGradleOperation.readFromCached(MapReadingCachedGradleOperation.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.CachedGradleOperation.call(CachedGradleOperation.groovy:58)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.populateContextLoader(GrailsCli.groovy:521)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:504)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:310)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:273)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:163)

I have also removed my `.gradle` folder still it showing me the error

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace with the `-stacktrace` argument

Comment: @GraemeRocher the stacktrace contains almost all my gradle dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have resolved this issue by installing gradle 2.13 on my machine then run **gradle clean** command.you can download gradle from here (http://wiki.deister.net/wiki/Linux:CentOS_install_gradle)

if this doesn't help then try to remove your local **.gradle** cache folder and then run gradle clean in your grails code.