# Grails 3.x update - bootRun failed

Tags: grails

I have upgraded small application from Grails 2.2 to Grails 3.2.3. After resolving compilation issues everything looks OK, but bootRun is failing and there is no obvious clue why.

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        maven { url "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/" }
        maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.6"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.4"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "testmonitor"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/" }
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1"
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client'
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.7.1'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"

    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ['-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always']
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

A log with `gradle --debug` (cant see any issue here) can be downloaded [from Sharepoint](https://vendavo-my.sharepoint.com/personal/znevrly_vendavo_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=JJWRRYyt6JLLmKH%2fpiS6uBctQ10FDYdD0rNo9CfvGxc%3d&docid=0466ad84c1e844c2383af1fe997a9d98f&rev=1).

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3, when I run grails run-app I am getting the same result. I can not find any option to log/info grails command. 
[running grails run-app][1]

UPDATE: now [grails run-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGj2E.png) seems OK, but htpp 404 is returned.

Comment: Could you post the errors you get ?

Comment: I copied your `build.gradle` into your question. We shouldn't have to download any files to understand what you're asking. If you select a block of code and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K it will be indented by four spaces, which tells Stack Overflow to treat it as code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more help on formatting. I also made it more clear that your log file is a download.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was hurrying up :(

Comment: I would like to post errors but I can not see any of them. I posted complete log and I am blind or there is no fatal error.

Comment: What about `grails run-app`? Is this command makes nothing neither?

Comment: I edited post - it's the same, just hanging and only daemon listener is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clear the **old gradle cache** too. follow the below link. I was getting almost same errors.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462689/3711185

Comment: Thanks. I did it, there was a lot of downloading but result is the same.

Comment: have you removed your C:\Users\znevrly\.gradle folder and then run gradle clean;grails clean ?

Comment: which gradle version do you have?

Comment: I have updated post. Both Gradle and Grails are latest at the time.

Comment: is it the homepage you are hitting or method of a controller? and is their any logs of the request?

Comment: I have tried both options, defined default page and concrete controller.

Comment: What is really strange, that I have change nothing and there is again stucked "Configuring Security plugin" message after grails run-app. I can not see any other logs like access protocol since this is embedded Tomcat.

Comment: UPDATE: Now I can run application from IDEA or cmd. Deployment it's quite fast but opening url it's a hell slow and CSS styles are not even loaded :(