# Fatal slow performance after Grails 3 upgrade

Tags: grails, grails3

I have updated small application to Grails 3.2.3. After some issues this is now resolved [Grails 3.x update - bootRun failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997634/grails-3-x-update-bootrun-failed)

But unfortunately the application is unusable. On my high-end laptop ThinkPad 460p I cant even load home page of application. It's loading for ages and then CSS styles are not loaded at all. There is no error messages for grails run-app or IDEA Run Configuration.

I have no idea what to do now, all configuration is described here [Grails 3.x update - bootRun failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997634/grails-3-x-update-bootrun-failed)

Thank you.

[Chrome network profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFM2P.png)

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: From 2.2.3 but right now this is not a issue for me. I had to go to latest 2.x.x version because simply 3.x is not feasible for my case.

Comment: Do you use the assets plugins?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am still on Grails 2.2 and why not. If there will be major reason to upgrade I will do a new try.

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a company firewall? Are your pages trying to access remote javascript and/or css files? The process trying to access these may hang or timeout eventually.

Comment: I have added Chrome network profile log. Windows 10 firewall is completely off and since this is localhost I don't think this should be issue. I am using SmartAdmin bootstrap template and it's fact that I had Grails 2. on Windows 7 but anyway. It should be working by default imho.